# Exporting an array within an ".then" doesnt work

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous, module

I'm new to NodeJS and are only familiar with Java. I'm trying to create a file that creates objects based on a database and adds them to an array. This array I want to be able to export so that I can use it throughout the whole program, but when I try to export the array it doesn't work. I've tried googling and understanding but haven't come across anything that was helpful unfortunately.

I hope that someone can help me understand

I've tried calling module.exports after the ".then" call, but it just returns an empty array because its async.
I've also tried calling module.exports = teams inside the .then call but it didn't work neither.

```
var teams = [];

function assignTeamsToClasses() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAllTeamsInDb((teamList) => {
            teamList.forEach((aTeam) => {
                let newTeam = new Team(aTeam['teamid'], aTeam['teamname'], aTeam['teamrank']);

                teams.push(newTeam);
            });
            resolve();
        });

    })
}

assignTeamsToClasses().then(() => {
    module.exports = teams;
});
```

main.js

```
var teams = require('./initialize.js');
console.log(teams);
```

I expect it to return all teams that are in the database. I know that array is not empty when called within the ".then" call, but the export part does not.

Answer (score 1):

Simple

1. the sequence `require()` + `console.log()` is synchronous
2. `assignTeamsToClasses()` is asynchronous, i.e. it updates `teams` at some unknown later point in time.

You'll have to design your module API to be asynchronous, e.g. by providing event listener interface or Promise interface that clients can subscribe to, to receive the "database update complete" event.

A proposal:

```javascript
module.exports = {
    completed: new Promise(resolve =>
        getAllTeamsInDb(teams => {
            const result = [];
            teams.each(aTeam =>
                result.append(new Team(aTeam.teamid,
                                       aTeam.teamname,
                                       aTeam.teamrank)
                )
            );
            resolve(result);
        })
    ),
};
```

How to use it:

```javascript
 const dbAPI = require('./initialize.js');
 dbAPI
     .completed
     .then(teams  => console.log(teams))
     .catch(error => /* handle DB error here? */);
```

Every caller who uses this API will

- either be blocked until the database access has been completed, or
- receive `result` from the already resolved promise and proceed with its `then()` callback.